# Does rust have a trait for a collection with `iter()` method or a resettable iterator?

Tags: rust, iterator, iterable, rust-itertools

It is useful for functions to accept a `dyn IntoIterator<blah>` object, which allows you to use `into_iter()`, but that requires taking ownership of the collection.

It seems like Rust lacks a trait for the `iter()` method. Does something like the `itertools` crate provide a replacement?

Is there an trait for a resettable/restartable iterator?

Is there some alternative for a function that:

1. Wants to iterate over a collection several times without cloning it.
2. Does not want to take ownership of anything.

I guess I could take `Iterator<Item=T>+Clone`, but that's a bit ugly (I'd have to use the iterator before using it the first time).

---

I should add my actual goal: I would like to make a bunch of functions that can take both `&[T]` or `&IndexSet<T>` (from indexmap crate) as arguments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> that requires taking ownership of the collection

No it does not, if the items can be references:

```rust
fn main() {
    let a = vec![1, 2, 3];
    do_it_twice_by_ref(&a);
    dbg!(a);
}

fn do_it_twice_by_ref<'a>(it: impl IntoIterator<Item = &'a u8> + Copy) {
    for i in it {
        dbg!(i);
    }
    for i in it {
        dbg!(i);
    }
}
```

This works because usually there is also a `impl IntoIterator for &Collection` ([see here for `IndexSet`](https://docs.rs/indexmap/latest/indexmap/set/struct.IndexSet.html#impl-IntoIterator-for-%26%27a%20IndexSet%3CT%2C%20S%3E)) which is implemented using the `iter` method.
And `Copy` comes for free on shared references.

Comment: This only allows me to iterate over the collection once.

Comment: Just add `Copy` to the constraints, shared references implement it anyways.

Comment: The now-edited version seems to work (thanks!). This is a little surprising to me, I'd expect the iterator to be exhausted after the first loop. 

It seems the compiler silently changes the first `it` to `it.copy()`, which is what it's supposed to do, but is curious here.

Comment: The first iterator is exhausted after the first loop, but since `it` didn't move (because it's `Copy`) the second loop just creates a new iterator with `into_iter` just like the first.

Comment: Sure, that makes sense. It just takes some familiarity with Rust to be used to the fact that the first `it` is the one that would have to be moved, and that moves are replaced with copies invisibly. Thank you again!

Comment: I understood your point a bit better. It's not the iterator that is copied, but the object with the IntoIter+Copy trait, such as &IndexSet.

Comment: You're right, fixed it.